# Extract names of these objects and add to new array in React Native?

Tags: arrays, react-native

I have these objects nested in array:
[image]

how can I extract the values of the objects names and add to new array in React native?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Are you looking for the result to be `["Banana", "Watermelon", "Pineapple"]`?

Comment: Yes of course @FredAstaire, can you please please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. If your original array is:

```
const array = [
  { id: 4, name: "Banana" },
  { id: 5, name: "Watermelon" },
  { id: 3, name: "Pineapple" },
]
```

you can create a new array by doing the following:

```
const namesArray = array.map((item) => item.name)
```

`namesArray` is:

```
["Banana", "Watermelon", "Pineapple"]
```